# How to add span tags to this link type in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add span tags to the following link in ruby?

```
<%= link_to l(:label_demo), {:action => 'test', :class => 'link' %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the `link_to` function a *block* as an argument where you can put whatever you want to sit between the `<a>` and `</a>`.

Check out this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html and this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html for more information on the `link_to` and `tag` functions.